# Is possible to access to html outsite the iframe (from the iframe)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.x.js"></script></meta>
<body>
<iframe src="myiframe.html">
</iframe>
<div class="dialog" style="display:none;">
 Hello world!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(myiframe.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.dialog').show();
</script>
```

Maybe using AJAX?

Comment: You can access parent window from the iframe and then can execute its script accordingly.

Comment: `window.top` gives you access to the parent window of an iFrame from within the iFrame.

Answer (score 3):

You can access like this

```
var parentBody = window.parent.document.body;
$(".dialog", parentBody).show();
```

Comment: But only if the parent has the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

If an iframe and page have the same domain (this actually means comply with the same domain policy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
then you can easily access the page window object via

```
var parentPage = window.parent;
```

And then call

```
parentPage.$('.dialog').show();
```

BUT if the domains do not match you will get a security exception here.